# Hook_view_pre_render(&$view) to alter field_title link locations

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I have a function in a custom module:

```
function mashavumodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    dsm($view);
}
```

After clearing the cache, I had a dump of $view but know my question is:

If I want to alter the location the the field_title links to, what part of the $view array should I alter and is hook_views_pre_render the best hook to use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify what type of changes you want to make, but in general, yes, hook_views_pre_render is a good place to change the way the View looks when actually rendered.

You will find the hits from views in `$view->results`, and that is where you will want to make changes.

Note though that you may not even need the hook, you can use replacement patterns, as in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32277/how-can-i-concatenate-two-fields-in-a-view) to accomplish many simple, and some advanced, changes to fields.

Comment: Thanks, using replacement patterns is defiantly the way to go.